# Regarding "in regards to" in the (new?) MCVE page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, wording

I just noticed that the close reasons dialog now includes a link to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.  I like the advice there, but something caught mine eyes, perhaps because it's emphasized:

[image: "in regards to"]

This rang wrong to me, and some Googling pointed out that, while "in regards to" does show up now and then, it's nonstandard usage.  (e.g., [IN REGARDS TO, WITH REGARD TO](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/regards.html)).  Could this be adjusted?  Candidates include:

- If your question isn't in regard to a compiler error…
- If your question doesn't regard a compiler error…
- If your question doesn't concern a compiler error…
- If your question isn't about a compiler error…
- …

Comment: "isn't *about* a compiler error" seems equally understandable. Maybe we should lose the emphasis too.

Comment: [Beware the giant s](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/220332)

Comment: @m0sa I don't mind, but why remove the [tag:spelling] tag, whose description says, "For discussing spelling-related edits, asking about preferred spellings, or *reporting spelling problems on the site itself*." ?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I had a feeling you wanted to substitute the whole _in regards to_ phrase, rather than just discuss what the correct spelling of the word _regards_ is. Perhaps it's just me not being a native speaker, as spelling means the order of letters in a _single_ word to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right; that read a little strangely.

Changed to "If your question isn’t *about* a compiler error..."